# custom class being passed to my view from my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

```
namespace JJ.WebAppliance
{
    public class ReportingTotalsViewModel
    {
        public DataTable MonthByMonth { get; set; }
        public DataTable MonthlyComparisons { get; set; }
        public DataTable Books_Issued_Location_Totals { get; set; }
        public DataTable Inventory_By_Location_Totals { get; set; }
        public DataTable Books_Issued_Vs_Closed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller

```
ReportingTotalsViewModel dataTable = new ReportingTotalsViewModel();
var viewAndDataTable = new List<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>();
...
return View(viewAndDataTable);
```

How do I access "viewAndDataTable" in my view?

My View

```
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (DataRow row in ???)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@row["Month"]</td>
                                    <td>@row["# Issued"]</td>
                                    <td>@row["# Closed"]</td>
                                    <td>@row["% Closed"]</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

Comment: How does your view look like ?

Comment: You can create a model in view like below in the view. @model IEnumerable> Now modle has your data.. Said by someone then deleted it. How would you do that?

Comment: You can pass any type of object to a view. If you want to pass List<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>() to the view, declare @model List<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>() in the view. make sure you have System.Data.SqlClient declared in your web.config of your view . Then you can just iterate the Model

Answer (score 1):

> How do I access "viewAndDataTable" in my view?

You could also use `ViewBag/ViewData` to pass data from controller to view.
For example,

Action:

```
var viewAndDataTable = new List<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>();
//populate the list

@ViewData["ViewAndDataTable"] = viewAndDataTable;
return View();
```

View:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<String, DataTable> item in (List<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>)@ViewData["ViewAndDataTable"])
{

    @foreach (DataRow row in item.Value.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@row["Month"]</td>
            <td>@row["# Issued"]</td>
            <td>@row["# Closed"]</td>
            <td>@row["% Closed"]</td>     
        </tr>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `@model` directive, located at the top of your View file:

```
 @model IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>
```

With that in place, you can now start using your (View) Model and its properties in your View:

```
   @model IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>

<h1>@Model</h1>
```

Thanks to the fact that you specify a strong type as the Model of the View, you will get help accessing members of the object through IntelliSense and your code will be validated during the Build process, to make sure that you only use properties/methods found on the Model object.